# How to create popup panel using JavaScript & CSS, no libraries?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to create popup panel centered on the screen with rounded corners (scrollbars are not neccessary; using jquery min) similar to this:

[image: Panel]

So far I am:

```
  function (package){

    document.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
    getParent(e.target);
    var node1 = $("#make_it_easy_styles");
    var node2 = $("#make_it_easy_panel");
    if ( node1.length ) node1.remove();
    if ( node2.length ) node2.remove();

    $("html > head").append("<style id=make_it_easy_styles>div#make_it_easy_panel { float:left; position: relative; left:10%; top:20%; border-radius: 2em; font-familly:'Arial Black'; font-size:13px; }</style>\n\r");      
    $("body").append("<div id=make_it_easy_panel></div>");
    $('div#panel').append("<ul>");
    var level = elements.length;
    for (var level = elements.length; 
        level>1 ; 
        level--)
      {
      $('div#make_it_easy_panel ul').append("<li>" + elements.collection[level].tag + "</li>\r\n");
      }    
    });


  }
```

Why do I not see any popup? I was testing this in debuger and I did not found any error. Also I would like to hide the panel or remove it when user clicks outside of the div. How to do it?

Comment: "var level = elements.length;" what is elements ?

Comment: Collection of elements data. it loops 9x and adds some text to li tags. Cuz elements.length is 9.

Comment: This might be helpful to you. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div#panel').append("<ul>");
    var level = elements.length;
    for (var level = elements.length; 
        level>1 ; 
        level--)
      {
      $('div#make_it_easy_panel ul').append("<li>" + elements.collection[level].tag + "</li>\r\n");
      }    
    });
```

I think you have to change `$('div#panel').append("<ul>");` with `$('div#make_it_easy_panel').append("<ul>")`

Comment: Exactly, purpose of my style is to reverse order. It is not that important what number is elements.lengths, it must be greater than 1. I have tested it with 8, not with 9, sorry. So I have passed the loop 8x. But I think if the css styles are correct and if I did used the JQuerry correctly? I did not did this before so I wonder where the div -> ul list disappeared. Before few hours I was able to see it, that was before I did some major changes. I have added float: left and position relative and now it is not visible.

Comment: see my edited answer, I think this might be the cause of your troubles

Comment: Thanks, this was it. This was the major change. I edited the labels and forgot to check the references. Now I see this: li items: `DIV`
`MAIN`
`SECTION`
`DIV` which is a list of elements (I do not see the list complely, it is in the bottom of the page). Currently it is placed in bottom left of the page. Do you have some tips how to move the div e.g. to center of the screen or so, just to be visible near the position which I am inspecting (the function is called from click event handler so I want to display it near the position where I clicked).

Comment: Yes, this is great. Thank you